# Can I have gcc ignore #warning directives

Tags: compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, compiler-directives

I am writing code that links to something that has many #warning directives scattered throughout. Seeing them pop up every time makes it very difficult to notice warnings in my own code. Is there a way to ignore the #warning directive?

Comment: you could find and replace "#warning" with "//#warning"

Comment: Of course I could remove all of the warning pragmas but there are many and clearly there for a reason. I would like to temporarily disable them while debuging my own code but not actually mess with the code that is not maintained by me. But if there is no other way I will end up doing exactly what you suggested.